# Updating @types/sass-loader causes error TS2314: Generic type 'Options<sync>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: types, sass, yarnpkg, package.json, sass-loader

I have just upgraded a few dependencies in my NuxtJS project that uses SASS. The project now runs into this error when building (I do understand the error but this isn't coming from my own code):

`../node_modules/@types/sass-loader/interfaces.d.ts:410:43 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Options<sync>' requires 1`

Here is the file mentionned in the error :
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sass-loader/interfaces.d.ts

As you can see below, the main change I've done in the upgrade is the switch from `node-sass` to `sass`, updated `sass-loader` and some eslint packages (even though I believe eslint has nothing to do with the error above).

BEFORE :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^5.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.0.3",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "express": "^4.18.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-2"
  }
```

AFTER :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^9.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.0.3",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.0",
    "jest": "^28.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-2"
  }
```

Inspecting my yarn.lock file, `sass-loader` is also needed with a different version by `"@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",` which is listed under my dependencies.

```
"@nuxt/types@^2.15.8":
  version "2.15.8"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@nuxt/types/-/types-2.15.8.tgz#1249de448f68169fe17e9379ee7b5caa0eb336b0"
  integrity sha512-zBAG5Fy+SIaZIerOVF1vxy1zz16ZK07QSbsuQAjdtEFlvr+vKK+0AqCv8r8DBY5IVqdMIaw5FgNUz5py0xWdPg==
  dependencies:
     ...
     "@types/sass-loader" "8.0.1"
     ...
     sass-loader "10.1.1"
```

So, my question is : where did I make a mistake ? is this some kind of dependency conflict/error ? or a bug from sass-loader ?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Hi @pipo92 , no unfortunately I could not find a solution to this issue.. I ended up reverting to using node-sass for the time being. I will retry this upgrade in a few weeks